# Ссылка не двигается вниз

Tags: css3

Не могу сдвинуть ссылку вниз, в стороны они двигаются без проблем, а по вертикали объекты не двигаются.

```css
.avtoriz {
  border: 3px solid #BF0000;
  color: white;
  background-color: #BF0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 890px;
  margin-top: 890px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.regis {
  border: 3px solid #BF0000;
  color: white;
  background-color: #BF0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 890px;
  margin-top: 870px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<a class="avtoriz" href="/login.php">авторизация</a><br />
<a class="regis" href="/signup.php">регистрация</a>
```

Comment: Сделайте пример воспроизводимым и добавьте свой HTML

Comment: `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если добавить `display: inline-block`, то все будет работать.

```css
a {
  border: 3px solid #BF0000;
  color: white;
  background-color: #BF0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/login.php">авторизация</a><br />
<a href="/signup.php">регистрация</a>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```css
.avtoriz {
  border: 3px solid #BF0000;
  color: white;
  background-color: #BF0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 890px;
  margin-top: 890px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
}

.regis {
  border: 3px solid #BF0000;
  color: white;
  background-color: #BF0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 890px;
  margin-top: 890px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a class="avtoriz" href="/login.php">авторизация</a><br /><br><br>
<a class="regis" href="/signup.php">регистрация</a>
```

Нужно добавить position: absolute;